# NSFetchedResultsController and Tables using Relationships

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

As a simple example lets say I have 2 entities with a many to many relationship.  The first entity is called "Projects" and the second "Employees".  The project entity can have 1 or more employees and employees can be on one or more projects.

Again for simplicity Project has an attribute called projectName and a to many relationship with Employee called withEmployees.  Conversely Employee has employeeName and a to many relationship to projects called myProjects.

Using NSFetchedResultsController I want a table that will have projectName as the section name and employeeName for the the rows.  Using Project as the fetched entity I can easily get each project and create the appropriate section name.  However, the issue comes when calculating the numberOfRowsInSection.  As the fetched results pulled back one record for the project the numberofrows sees only one entity as it doesn't look into the NSSet found in the .withEmployees relationship. This means that only one employee will be output rather than the count of the number within the NSSet relationship.

How is this issue best overcome to use a to many relationship within a table?

Thanks.

Here is the code for the fetchedcontroller:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Projects" 
     inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *firstSort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"projectName"
                                                                      ascending:NO];

NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[firstSort];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];


_fetchedController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                    managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                                                      sectionNameKeyPath:@"projectName"  
                                                                                 cacheName:nil];
```

Comment: Please show us the code you're using to set up the fetchedResultsController.

Comment: Added at bottom of post.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally found the answer.  The entity relationships I had were all fine as described above.  The issue again was to get the correct number of rows returned through the to many relationship.  I solved that in the following manner:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    Projects *project = [self.fetchedController objectAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:section]];

return [project.withEmployees count];

}
```

With the above I used the appropriate section and since I know that there is always one row that contains a set of unknown size, I created an indexpath that looked to the one and only one header record (the project) for each section.  I then just looked into the NSSet that makes up the relationship and simply return the count of that.  Now we get the correct number of rows per section.

As for the cells themselves:

```
Projects *project = [self.fetchedController objectAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:atIndex.section]];

UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:atIndex];

NSArray *empArray = [project.withEmployees allObjects];

Employee *employee = [empArray objectAtIndex:atIndex.row];

cell.textLabel.text = employee.firstName;

}
```

The key here was to get the one section record and then pull out all of the data that makes up the to many relationship.  Again I need to create an indexpath in order to only get the parent record.  Now using the rows I can iterate through the array to get each element.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [self.fetchedResultsController sections][section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}
```

This assumes you've passed the correct `sectionNameKeyPath:` in the fetched results controller's `-initWithFetchRequest:managedObjectContext:sectionNameKeypath:cacheName:` call.

Side note: relationship names generally follow the same naming rules as properties or attributes. Instead of `myProjects` and `withEmployees`, use `projects` and `employees`. It makes your code read better: `fred.projects` instead of `fred.myProjects`, `lawnmower.employees` instead of `lawnmower.myEmployees`.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  The problem with what you pose is that it does not return more than 1.  For the number of rows it will have to look into the NSSet and count objects there.  What happens is that it finds one Project record and thus returns number of rows as 1.  Indeed there is one project but it contains an NSSet that itself has say 2 employees that should be returned under the section header project name.  Again returning only 1 means that it will only ever show 1 employee under each project rather than the number actually in the set.

Comment: In response to your additional text above that was not in the first post.  The entity would be Projects and the sectionNameKeyPath would be projectName (since this is the section heading I would be looking for).  Appreciate the notes on the naming convention.  If I recall in watching the Stanford iOS class, they used naming closer to what I did but I take your point.

Comment: If you're seeing only one related object in each `Project` section, that's a sign that your relationship is not being connected properly. The call to `-sections` will give you one instance of `id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>` for each section. Inspect those: look at `indexTitle`, `name`, `numberOfObjects`, and `objects`, and see if anything looks suspicious.

Comment: What I am missing in what you are saying is where it would be inspecting the number of objects in withEmployees?  The entity is Projects and the section name is projectName.  It is not clear why your code would be looking at anything other than the returned project record which has one record although that one record does have a relationship that contains a set.  Still this is one overall record and nothing here tells it to look into the set.

Comment: Closely read the documentation for the `-sections` method on `NSFetchedResultsController`. It does not behave as you describe. If you are seeing only one employee per project, that could be because you are inserting multiple project instances for a particular name, instead of adding employees to a single project instance for that name.

Comment: I have a utility that looks into the DB file so I can see the data.  I have added data through my app such that I have 1 project and 3 employees.  Within my app I assigned 2 of the 3 to the only project there.  When I go back to my own assignment screen (which looks into the Employee entity that has a predicate based on projectName) I can see that 2 of the employees are checked as it should be.  If I look at the core data viewing utility I can see 1 project record that has .withEmployees pointing to the two employee records of interest.  The employee records each point to 1 project record.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet so asking this as an answer and possible addition to the code above:

I managed to retrieve the relationship's entity in an NSSet and show it in the tableview.

However I'm now trying to implement slide-to-delete to that tableview and my NSFRC can't register the deletion of the object in the relationship array.

In this example this would mean: I can delete a Project object, but if I delete an Employee object it crashes because it registers (0,0) rows added/removed.

I fetch it the same way and then delete that object:

```
NSArray *empArray = [project.withEmployees allObjects];

Employee *employee = [empArray objectAtIndex:atIndex.row];

[context deleteObject:employee];
```

Do you have a work around by any chance?

I currently have no predicate in my NSFRC could that change things if it checked the project.employee to something? Or should I work with 2 NSFRCs, one that loads Projects and sets sections, and one that loads Employees and loads rows? I think they might still interfere when detecting a deleted object.

Comment: From your description you are looking to remove an employee from a project not an employee from the overall database.  If you were going to do the latter than you'd simply query up the employee entity and delete the record in question which would then update the relationship in the other connected entities.  However, if you want the employee to remain but you want them removed from the project then you have to update the NSSet within the ".withEmployees" relationship of Project.  You cannot delete the record but rather will need to update the NSSet with only the employees you want.

Comment: Thank you. I indeed needed to update in some way but kept getting 1560 and 1570 cocoa errors. This was because I had the relationship set as required thus it needed that relationship object passed every time it was saved apparently (I thought once at creation was enough). I made it optional and managed to empty the NSSet with [[myDepartement mutableSetValueForKey:@"employees"] removeAllObjects]; Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! NSFRC is turning out to be quite the nemesis when using relationships :)